# SPARQL query for Dublin Core

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology, rdfs, dublin-core

I'm new in the field of ontology. I'm using the Dublin Core as an additional ontology to the ontology that I'm creating which is a curriculum ontology. But, I'm having trouble on how I can retrieve certain information.

For example, I have a class named, `Bibliographic Resource`, this is a class in the Dublin Core ontology. In this class, I have a member named `Introduction_to_Computer_Science_1` and in this member, I have a data property named, `Alternative Title` with a string value named `ICS Book`. I want to retrieve the Alternative title of the member which is the `ICS Book`.  I'm using SPARQL as my query language and Protégé as my ontology tool. This is my query

```
SELECT ?title 
    WHERE{
         <http://semanticweb.org/LearningPlanOntology#Introduction_to_Computer_Science_1> dc:'Alternative Title' ?title.
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my query?

Comment: The URI for the 'Alternative Title' property is `http://purl.org/dc/terms/alternative`, so using `<http://purl.org/dc/terms/alternative>` should get around any syntax issue with the label.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and worked. I think you might have a syntax issue:

```
prefix : <http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/curriculum#>
prefix dcterms:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
SELECT distinct *
WHERE{
   :Introduction_to_Computer_Science_1 dcterms:alternative ?title
}
```

[image]